# XSS Attacks prevention with Ajax Get & POST requests

Tags: html, ajax, xss

I have minimal knowledge over preventing XSS vulnerabilities of how it can be done especially with form inputs by not allowing the special characters like <,> etc., But the question that i have is with Ajax :

- Get Request : How efficiently it can be prevented for the query string params.
- POST Request : Is the data sent via POST request could still be a cause for XSS attack OR POST requests prevents the XSS attacks.

Please do help me in understanding this.

Comment: Update you knowledge first by reading [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_AJAX_Vulnerabilities_(OWASP-AJ-001)) article.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeroen for the response. I will go through the details.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have to understand about XSS is that it targets the browser, not the server. If tags are injected in your GET or POST requests, this is irrelevant to the server. It only matters how you present that data back to the user.

Say you have a field in the database where the content is user-generated input. When presenting this data to any viewer, filter it for HTML tags, or filter it before storing it, the order doesn't matter.

There's however a different form of XSS attack that you don't seem to be picturing here. An external site generating URLs and POST requests towards yours. This is legal and have to be treated in order to prevent things like `changepassword.php?newpass=hacked` (crude example). The POST equivalent to this is also possible.

What many websites do is generate what is commonly referred to as "postkey", a random value or phrase that is generated and bound to the user's current session and is attached to all POST and GET calls that modify information, either in the form of a Query String variable (GET) or a hidden field in a form (POST). All important POSTs and GETs should include it for validation.

An external attacker won't be able to know what the postkey is, since they can't do "cross-site reading" prior to a successful XSS attack, so any attempt to submit a POST or GET request directed towards your website will be missing this key and should be harmless.

Comment: +1 to mention something very important when you say it targets the browser, not the server. It's the customers and website reputation that's at risk.

Comment: @Havenard, Thanks a lot for the response. For current implementation that i have in my project, it has been integrated with spring CSRF security. So all the ajax requests will be done with _csrf token in it? Will this help me in preventing the XSS attacks.